# Custom renderer for Tabbed page in Android: Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am working on a `Xamarin.Forms` application. I have this tabbed page renderer in iOS:

```
public class TabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
{
    private MainPage _page;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            _page = (MainPage)e.NewElement;
        }
        else
        {
            _page = (MainPage)e.OldElement;
        }

        try
        {
            var tabbarController = (UITabBarController)this.ViewController;

            if (null != tabbarController)
            {
                tabbarController.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabBarReselected;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }
    }

    private void OnTabBarReselected(object sender, UITabBarSelectionEventArgs e)
    {

        var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;
        var playTab = tabs.Children[4];

        if (TabBar.SelectedItem.Title == "Play")
        {
            if (tabs != null)
            {
                playTab.Title = "Pause";
                playTab.Icon = "pause.png";
            }
            App.pauseCard = false;

        }
        else 
        {
            if (tabs != null)
            {
                playTab.Title = "Play";
                playTab.Icon = "play.png";
            }
            App.pauseCard = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This basically changes the icon on my `Play` tab to pause and play. This is working good in iOS. But I am struggling on how to have the same function (basically convert this to Android) in Android side.

Can any point me to the right direction? Basically help me? :-)

Note: I am pretty new with Android development.

**EDIT:** This is what it would look like in iOS.

Pause Mode: 
[image]
Play Mode:
[image]

Comment: Hi, can you provide a picture? And then I can help you achieve it in Android. I am android developer.

Comment: @JoeLv I have edited my post to add some images. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [blog](https://montemagno.com/dynamically-changing-xamarin-forms-tab-icons-when-select/) post by Xamarin's James Montemagno which explains how to achieve this requirement.

Basically, it uses Custom Tab which inherits from TabbedPage which initialize an event `UpdateIcons` to be fired on Tab Current Page Changed event `CurrentPageChanged`

```
public class MyTabs : TabbedPage
{
    //always save a reference to the current page
    Page currentPage;
    public MyTabs()
    {
        //create the pages and set the view models
        //you could also do this in the page code behind
        Children.Add(new TabIconsPage
        {
            BindingContext = new Tab1ViewModel
            {
                IsSelected = true
            }
        });
        Children.Add(new TabIconsPage2
        {
            BindingContext = new Tab2ViewModel()
        });

        currentPage = Children[0];

        //Register for page changes
        this.CurrentPageChanged += Handle_CurrentPageChanged;
    }

    //Update the IsSelected state and trigger an Event that anyone can loop into.
    public event EventHandler UpdateIcons;
    void Handle_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentBinding = currentPage.BindingContext as IIconChange;
        if (currentBinding != null)
            currentBinding.IsSelected = false;

        currentPage = CurrentPage;
        currentBinding = currentPage.BindingContext as IIconChange;
        if (currentBinding != null)
            currentBinding.IsSelected = true;

        UpdateIcons?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Now Android needs a custom renderer to subscribe to the UpdateIcons event and perform icon changes

```
public class MyTabs : TabbedPage
{
    //always save a reference to the current page
    Page currentPage;
    public MyTabs()
    {
        //create the pages and set the view models
        //you could also do this in the page code behind
        Children.Add(new TabIconsPage
        {
            BindingContext = new Tab1ViewModel
            {
                IsSelected = true
            }
        });
        Children.Add(new TabIconsPage2
        {
            BindingContext = new Tab2ViewModel()
        });

        currentPage = Children[0];

        //Register for page changes
        this.CurrentPageChanged += Handle_CurrentPageChanged;
    }

    //Update the IsSelected state and trigger an Event that anyone can loop into.
    public event EventHandler UpdateIcons;
    void Handle_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentBinding = currentPage.BindingContext as IIconChange;
        if (currentBinding != null)
            currentBinding.IsSelected = false;

        currentPage = CurrentPage;
        currentBinding = currentPage.BindingContext as IIconChange;
        if (currentBinding != null)
            currentBinding.IsSelected = true;

        UpdateIcons?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```